# pass class member function as argument from another member function of the same class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have provided a simpler version of the problem, that I am dealing with.

I have class `Entity`, which has a `map` of a `user` object. For simplicity, I have added only one element(`name`). I have implemented `getter` and `setter` around the `userMap` object.

The `wrapper` function is required for me, to handle a critical situation because of a multi-threaded case. (not shown here). I have somehow implemented a working example by going through a few SO threads.

But as you can see, I have to write `(id,arg)` tuple argument in three places while using `wrapper` function inside `procedure` function. Is there a way of implementing the same functionality by having some kind of placeholder for the function arguments so that calling the wrapper looks clean, i.e. `wrapper(1,static_cast<void*>(&name),function_ptr)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class Entity {
    public:
        struct user {
            int id;
            string name;
        };
        map<int,user> userMap;

        void getUserName(int id,void * arg);
        void setUserName(int id,void * arg);
        void procedure();
        void wrapper(int id,void*,std::function<void(int,void*)>);
};

void Entity::getUserName(int id,void *arg) {
    auto iter = userMap.find(id);

    if(iter != userMap.end()) {
        *static_cast<string*>(arg) = iter->second.name; 
    }
}

void Entity::setUserName(int id,void *arg) {
    auto iter = userMap.find(id);
    if(iter != userMap.end()) {
        iter->second.name = *static_cast<string*>(arg);
    }
}

void Entity::wrapper(int id,void *arg,std::function<void(int,void*)> func) {
    cout <<"\nSome Other critical task based on id"<< endl;

    // then call the callback
    func(id,arg);
}

void Entity::procedure() {
    cout <<"Procedure starts"<<endl;

    user u = {};
    u.id = 1;
    u.name = "abc";
    this->userMap[1] = u;

    string name;
    wrapper(1,static_cast<void*>(&name),[this](int id,void*arg){
        getUserName(id,arg);
    });
    cout <<"name :"<< name << endl;

    cout <<"\nSome processing..."<<endl;

    name = "def";
    wrapper(1,static_cast<void*>(&name),[this](int id,void*arg){
        setUserName(id,arg);
    });

    cout <<"\nSome more processing..."<<endl;

    wrapper(1,static_cast<void*>(&name),[this](int id,void*arg){
        getUserName(id,arg);
    });

    cout <<"name :"<< name << endl;

    cout <<"Procedure ends"<<endl;
}

int main() {
    Entity E;
    E.procedure();
}
```

Output:

```
Some Other critical task based on id
name :abc

Some processing...

Some Other critical task based on id

Some more processing...

Some Other critical task based on id
name :def
Procedure ends
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't e.g. `wrapper(1,static_cast<void*>(&name), getUserName);` doing the job by implicit conversion. Just a thought not tested ;)

Comment: @Korni. It shows, `invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Entity::getUserName(int, void*)’` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with a direct answer, but please read on to the caveat that follows it.

A simpler syntax for what you are trying to do would involve changing the type of the third parameter to `wrapper()`. Instead of converting member functions to non-member functions, just take the member function as a parameter.

```
void wrapper(int id, void* arg, void (Entity::* func)(int,void*))
{
    cout <<"\nSome Other critical task based on id"<< endl;
    (this->*func)(id, arg);
}
```

Then your calls would become simpler:

```
wrapper(1, static_cast<void*>(&name), &Entity::getUserName);
wrapper(1, static_cast<void*>(&name), &Entity::setUserName);
```

**However** is this really the approach you want to take? You are relying on people remembering to call the wrapper instead of calling the other member functions directly. If you forget to use the wrapper at some point, will you be able to track down the cause based on the symptoms? Do you even want to try?

A more robust approach would be to put the critical task in its own function, then have the getters and setters call that. Something more like:

```
void criticalStuff(int id)
{
    cout <<"Some critical task based on id\n";
}

void Entity::getUserName(int id, string & arg)
{
    criticalStuff(id); // Critical stuff first.

    auto iter = userMap.find(id);
    if(iter != userMap.end()) {
        arg = iter->second.name; 
    }
}

void Entity::setUserName(int id, const string & arg)
{
    criticalStuff(id); // Critical stuff first.

    auto iter = userMap.find(id);
    if(iter != userMap.end()) {
        iter->second.name = arg;
    }
}
```

Anyone adding new fields would still have to remember the critical stuff when writing new getters and setters, but the more common case (calling those functions) would handle the critical stuff automatically. Plus, you get to bring back type checking of parameters, since there appears to no longer be a reason to cast stuff to `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I think you're causing yourself problem by forcing the use of `lambda`, I know they are interesting, but often aren't very useful. In general keep it simply stupid (KISS) and in your case just divide the functions in two seperate functions.

```
class Entity {
    public:
        ...            
        void getUserName(int id,void * arg);
        void setUserName(int id,void * arg);
        void procedure();
        void criticalTask(int id); // critical task, based on id
};

void Entity::getUserName(int id,void *arg) {...}

void Entity::setUserName(int id,void *arg) {...}

void Entity::criticalTask(int id) {
    cout <<"\nSome Other critical task based on id"<< endl;
}

void Entity::procedure() {
    cout <<"Procedure starts"<<endl;

    ...

    criticalTask(id);
    getUserName(id, &name);

    ...

}

int main() {
    Entity E;
    E.procedure();
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me with a class member function. Please consider using a class member function only.

Comment: @Debashish Updated my answer

Comment: `this->getUserName` is an invalid use of a non-static member function name. The only way to form a pointer to member is with the `&Entity::getUserName` syntax.

Comment: @aschepler you're right thanks, just deleted this part. Avoiding function pointers & lambdas is also the better solution IMO.

Comment: `#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))`

`void Entity::wrapper(int id, void *arg, void (Entity::* func)(int, void*)) {
    cout <<"\nSome Other critical task based on id"<< endl;
    CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this,func)(id,arg);
}` - worked.